# MySql search columns and joined columns for text and order by count of columns joined

Tags: mysql, join, count

Is it possible to do the query below without the UNION?

To simplify, I have three tables "article", "article_tag" and "tag".

```
article:     { article_id, title,      content }
article_tag: { tag_id,     article_id          }
tag:         { tag_id,     tag                 }
```

If someone searches for "orange", I want to find articles tagged "orange" but also articles with "orange" in the title. 
I order the results by counting how many tags matched the query text.

This is how I currently do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select article.*, count(tag.tag) AS tag_count
    FROM article, article_tag, tag
    WHERE article.article_id = article_tag.article_id AND 
      article_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id AND
      tag.tag like "%orange%"
    GROUP BY article.article_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT article.*, 0 
    FROM article 
    WHERE article.title LIKE "%orange%"
) as t
GROUP BY t.article_id
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
```

I'm asking this because I'm using an ORM that doesn't accommodate for UNION's.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solves your problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select article.*, count(tag.tag) AS tag_count
    FROM article, article_tag, tag
    WHERE article.article_id = article_tag.article_id AND
      article_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id AND
     (tag.tag like "%orange%" OR article.title LIKE "%orange%")
)as t
GROUP BY t.article_id
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
```

Comment: This almost worked. The problem is that it doesn't count tags matching "orange", it counts all tags regardless of whether they match orange because the condition article.title LIKE "%orange%" satisfies them all.

Just to make it clear, I count the number of tags matching the query text (e.g. "orange") so I can order the results by relevance, the most relevant having the highest count.

Thanks though.